# How can a disease be transmissible animal-to-human but not human-to-human?

Tags: virology, infectious-diseases

I have heard some debate about whether or not the Wuhan virus can be transmitted human-to-human, but this doesn't make sense to me.  Why wouldn't it be able to?  Are there diseases that can only be transmitted from animals, not humans?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Viruses: Adaptation to a new host through repeated host jumps](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16972/viruses-adaptation-to-a-new-host-through-repeated-host-jumps)

Answer (score 1):

> I have heard some debate about whether or not the Wuhan virus can be transmitted human-to-human, but this doesn't make sense to me. Why wouldn't it be able to?

A virus has to be able to physically get out of one person and then into another in order to infect them.  If it can't do that, it can't spread between people.  Just because you can get a virus by (for example) eating an infected animal doesn't mean you'll be able to spread it to other people, at least without them eating you.

> Are there diseases that can only be transmitted from animals, not humans?

Yes, and this is very common.  Rabies for instance can be transmitted from hundreds or maybe even thousands of animals to humans, but is virtually incapable of moving between people because it infects the nervous system which severely limits the ability of the virus to get into another host.

Comment: I would think (though I'm far from an expert) that rabies is a bad example.  A person with rabies might well be able to infect another person if, like other animal vectors, they bit that person.  Better examples might be insect-borne diseases.

Comment: @jamesqf There are no documented cases of human transmission of rabies, so while it could in theory happen, it doesn't appear to in practice. It is possible viral shedding is too low in human saliva, or that paralysis sets in too quickly in people vs other animals.

Comment: Sorry, I mean human transmission through bites. People have gotten it from organ transplants if the donar was infected.

Comment: Though I would wonder if it's a matter of humans being unable to transmit rabies via bites, or of infected people being kept from biting others, or perhaps not having the instinct to bite.